# how link to magento review form in a specific jquery tab from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am using a magento template which uses jquery.tabs.min.js for displaying different product information in different tabs.

Now I would like to send customers mails with a direct link to the review form, which is at  the end of the third tab.

Unfortunatly the page if called from outside always opens with the first tab open.

So sending links with an additional hash from the tab id does not work.

I have already looked around many similiar threads but unfortunatly I am not very familiar with javascript, and I would need a realy detailed help, how to work this out and espacialy where to put the different snippets (i.e. inside the html of the page or in the js-file).

Something thar makes it maby more difficult is, that it would be helpful to not only open the third tab, but as well scroll down to the "review form" which is inside the third tab, at the bottom, and if there are more than a few reviews the visitor would not see the review directly.

So here is the html snippet, which represents my pages structure

```
<div id="product-tabs" class="gen-tabs gen-tabs-style-f">

            <ul class="tabs clearer">
                <li id="tab-description"><a class="current" href="#">Beschreibung</a></li>
                <li id="tab-additional"><a href="#">Zusatzinformation</a></li>
                <li id="tab-tabreviews"><a href="#">Bewertungen</a></li>
                <li id="tab-product.tags"><a href="#">Schlagworte</a></li>        
            </ul>
   <div class="tabs-panels">
            <h2 class="acctab" id="acctab-description">Beschreibung</h2>
                <div class="panel">    <h2>Details</h2>
                CONTENT
                </div>
            <h2 class="acctab" id="acctab-additional">Zusatzinformation</h2>
                <div class="panel">    <h2>Zusatzinformation</h2>
                CONTENT
                </div>
            <h2 class="acctab" id="acctab-tabreviews">Bewertungen</h2><div class="panel">
                <div class="box-collateral box-reviews" id="customer-reviews">
                CONTENT OF CUSTOMER REVIEWS
                    <div class="form-add">
                     <h2>Schreiben Sie Ihre eigene Kundenmeinung</h2>
                        <form action="http://www.mydomain.com/review/product/post/id/8/" method="post" id="review-form">
                        -->>HERE IS MY REVIEW FORM<<--
                    </div>
                </div>
            <h2 class="acctab" id="acctab-product.tags">Schlagworte</h2><div class="panel">
                <div class="box-collateral box-tags"> <h2>Schlagworte</h2>
                CONTENT
                </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Update:

Maybe it is possible to extend the already existing function which routes the visitor "on click" directly to the review form, to work as well, depending on a parameter given with the URL (ie. a hashtag) ? Here is the peace of code from the template:

```
<?php //Open the "Reviews" tab, when "X Review(s)" or "Be the first to review this product" links are clicked ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(function($){$("#goto-reviews, #goto-reviews-form").click(function(){if($("#product-tabs").hasClass("accor")){$("#product-tabs .tabs-panels").data("tabs").click($(".tabs-panels .acctab").index($("#acctab-tabreviews")))}else{$("#product-tabs .tabs").data("tabs").click($("#tab-tabreviews").index())}})});
    //]]>
    </script>
```

If anybody could help me with that? Should be somehow easy if one have skills in JS  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the ID of the tab to the query string?

```
Http://www.mysite.com/product-URL.html#acctab-tabreviews
```

Adding the I'd portion of the li element with a hash should work

Comment: Hi Andrew, and thank you for your comment. This does not work. Unfortunatly I have missed an important detail in my code example. (now I have completed it): the first tab gets the class "current" on page load. So I think thsi has to be changed somehow in case of links with  a hash